# Rotating an object to being straight in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, alignment

I'm working in a document with all kinds of electrical symbols. Now, there is this line with a 'hook' that needs to be straight again. It doesn't have any rotation information. How do I make the line and hook (pixel)perfectly straight? I know I can grab the pen tool and align the pixels manually, but I'm curious if there's a more simple way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to make a frame selection around the two anchor points to be aligned and click que align left/middle/right button at the top options bar.

The last anchor point selected becomes the key anchor point.